# Area form of a zero level set?

Tags: differential-forms

Given a zero level set $f(x,y,z)=0$, is it correct that the area form represented as
$\frac{dx \wedge dy}{f_z} = \frac{dy \wedge dz}{f_x} = \frac{dz \wedge dx}{f_y}$ when any of them is defined ?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: It may be close, but in its current form, not a chance. The same surface that is given by $f$ is also given by $2f$, and the area forms ought to be the same, but they won't be. Maybe normalize $f_x$ to $\frac{f_x}{\sqrt{f_z^2+f_y^2+f_z^2}}$ (and similar for the others)?

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply, Arthur.
It seems that your comment is true! I misunderstood. It was a great help:)
This formulation appeared in Introduction to Manifold by L.W.Tu, and I don’t have any idea what these forms mean.
Thank you very much!